# Filtering text according to indices and color words in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following **JsonData**:

```
{
    "text": "This is the text with many words",
    "annotation": [{
            "comment": "Comment A",
            "indices": [0, 3]
        },
        {
            "comment": "Comment B",
            "indices": [1, 2, 4]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to color words that belong to each comment so that

```
"This", "text"  ---> Red
```

and

```
"is", "the", "with" ---> blue.
```

1. I think it requires some filter or map function but I can't imagine it so I ask for a suggestion on how to "iterate" over words, and then over comments, and then over indices. (or maybe in a different order?)
2. I'd like to do it in React app. Is this the correct place for these calculations?

Code:

```
export default function PrettyPrint({ jsonData }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {jsonData && jsonData.text.split(' ').map((line) => (
                line 
                // Should the function that filters words for each color be here?
            ))}

        </div>
    )
}
```

I am new to javascript, react, and functional programming so any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly,** You can build `index_mapping` with the content structure that looks like

```
[{"txt":"This","index":0},{"txt":"is","index":1},{"txt":"the","index":2},{"txt":"text","index":3},{"txt":"with","index":4},{"txt":"many","index":5},{"txt":"words","index":6}]
```

**Secondly,** You can use `Array#map` to concatenate all words matching with `index_mapping`

```js
const data = {
    "text": "This is the text with many words",
    "annotation": [{
            "comment": "Comment A",
            "indices": [0, 3]
        },
        {
            "comment": "Comment B",
            "indices": [1, 2, 4]
        }
    ]
};

const index_mapping = data.text.split(" ").map((txt, index) => ({txt, index}));

const words_in_red_color = data.annotation[0].indices.map(numeric_index => index_mapping.find(r => r.index === numeric_index)?.txt);
const words_in_blue_color = data.annotation[1].indices.map(numeric_index => index_mapping.find(r => r.index === numeric_index)?.txt);

console.log({words_in_red_color, words_in_blue_color});
```

---

It should be processed after fetching data, you have `jsonData` then normalize data like my answer. After that, you can render components as you wish. Good luck !

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @DavidS1992

Comment: Yes, it does help me and I think I get it. However I have no idea how can I use this code in react component. My `jsonData` is fetched via some API. Any ideas about that? Should it be processed after fetching or rather in the component?

Comment: It is definitely helpful but my question concerns this situation in React so it doesn't answer the question entirely

Comment: It should be processed after fetching data, you have `jsonData` then normalize data like my answer. After that, you can render component as you wish @DavidS1992

Comment: maybe you could add this comment to your answer? Then the answer will be complete. 
With one exception: the processing should be done in the backend I think because useEffect will not wait for the data from API and can throw errors while trying to modify the values that are not fetched yet.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look at it @DavidS1992

Answer (score 1):

In your `.map` function you can get the index :

```js
[1,2,3].map((value, index) => {...})
```

So you can compare your index with your array of index like this :

```js
jsonData.split(" ").map((value, index) => {
  if (jsonData.annotation[0].indices.includes(index)) {
    // this is the annotation [0]
  }

  if (jsonData.annotation[1].indices.includes(index)) {
    // this is the annotation [1]
  }
})
```